# Dynamic mapping not applied, and is missing in _mapping

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a dynamic mapping that applies to string fields or date fields,

```
{
  "xx": {
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "dates": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "date*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "YYYY-mm-dd",
              "doc_values": true
            }
          },
          "string_fields": {
            "mapping": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "store": false,
              "doc_values": true,
              "type": "string"
            },
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But when I applied it to an index, the "dates" part is missing, only the string_fields remained,

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: You are matching on star for both types, how could they be distinguished then?

Answer (score 0):

Date mapping:

```
"dynamic_date_formats": [
           "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
           "YYYY-mm-dd"
         ],
```

`YYYY-mm-dd`, this is the format which you want to match for the date field.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how you applied that mapping to an index, but the proper way is this for an index called `test_index` and a type called `test_type`:

```
PUT /test_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "test_type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "dates": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "date*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "YYYY-mm-dd",
              "doc_values": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "mapping": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "store": false,
              "doc_values": true,
              "type": "string"
            },
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"dynamic_date_formats": [
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
 "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"],

"dynamic_templates":[
{
    "string_fields": {
    "mapping": {
    "index": "not_analyzed",
    "type": "string"
},
    "match_mapping_type": "string",
     "match": "*"
```

}],

Comment: Perhaps you should [edit] your answer to include a description why this answers the question. By adding a description you help readers understand the intricacies of the solution and prevent them from making the same mistake twice.